# What is the <track> element?

Tags: html

Can someone explain what the track element in HTML is for in very simple terms?

Comment: Are you speaking of this? http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#timed-text-tracks

Comment: So are they text tracks?

Comment: *If* this is what you're talking about. Can you give more context for the question?

Comment: @deceze yes the link you provided is what I'm talking about.

Comment: A bit late, but this might help: [WebVTT and Video Subtitles](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/05/html5/webvtt-and-video-subtitles).

Comment: In chrome, you might have to goto chrome://flags and enable it. There is an "Enable <track> element" option

Answer (score 2):

The track element lets you define subtitles, captions, descriptions, chapters, or metadata for either an audio or video element.

Sources:

- [track element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-track-element)
- [text tracks](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#text-track)
- [media elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#media-element)

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that a DVD can have multiple audio or video tracks, the `<track>` element allows HTML5 video to do the same. This is primarily useful for things like adding subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

> The src attribute gives the address of the text track data. The value must be a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces. This attribute must be present.

[Source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#attr-track-src).

Comment: do I need to specify the kind attribute? what is the default value is the kind attribute is not indicated.

Answer (score 1):

As it says [in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#timed-text-tracks), they're for:

- subtitles
- captions
- descriptions
- chapters
- metadata

Although this part of the spec has been in a lot of flux in recent months and it isn't finalised yet, [this presentation](http://blog.gingertech.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/HTML5AuDesc/) will give you some idea of the intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

The  element allows authors to specify explicit external timed tracks for media elements. It does not represent anything on its own.

see [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/track)

Comment: That you can only use &lt;track> inside a &lt;video> or &lt;audio> element.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for shameless self promotion, but I wrote an article about the track element for HTML5 Rocks: [Getting Started With The Track Element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/).

EDIT: removed examples from post: as Jörn pointed out (see below) Chrome was crashing if you scrolled a video with a track element offscreen. This seems to have been fixed now (in 19.0.1053.0 canary) but I'll leave the examples out for the moment.

Comment: just tried your article in the current chrome canary (19.xxxx) and it makes it crash... :)

Comment: You're right :( -- not sure what's changed. Looking at this now.

Comment: Thank you Jörn. There seems to have been a change that causes the track element to crash when it's scrolled offscreen. Reproduce crash here: http://www.samdutton.com/track/bug/offscreen.html. Bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79363

Comment: actually the current canary seems to be buggy all together - keeps on crashing on jsfiddle and some other pages as well :/